# How can I refresh a child component from its grandparent?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter

I have LWC 3 components, `grandparent`, `parent`, `child`. `grandparent` should get records of `Assignment__c`. For each `Assignment__c`, we display a `parent` instance. `parent` gets records of `Timecard__c` and for each one we display a `child` instance.

`grandparent` has a button which submits all timecards and calls `SubmitAllTimecards.cls` to do so. When using `refreshApex(this.wiredAssignmentResult)` on `grandparent`, the `child` component doesn't refresh. How can I achieve this? Here is my code (assume all variables are populated):

**grandparent.html**

```
<template>
    <!--some other stuff-->
    <template lwc:if={assignments}>
        <template for:each={assignments} for:item="assignment">
            <div class="my-card slds-p-around_small slds-m-around_small" key={assignment.Id}>
                <c-timecard-project-card assignment={assignment} ></c-timecard-project-card>
            </div>
            <lightning-button onclick={handleSubmitAllTimecards} label="Submit all timecards" title="Submit all timecards"></lightning-button>
        </template>
    </template>
</template>
```

**grandparent.js**

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire, track } from 'lwc';
import { refreshApex } from '@salesforce/apex';
import getAssignments from '@salesforce/apex/TimecardHelper.getAssignments';
import submitAllTimecards from '@salesforce/apex/TimecardHelper.submitAllTimecards';
import USER_ID from '@salesforce/user/Id';

export default class ParentTimecard extends LightningElement {
    @api userId = USER_ID;
    @api timecards;
    @api assignments;
    @api wiredAssignmentsResult;

    error;
    
    connectedCallback() {
        //do stuff
    }

    @wire(getAssignments, { userId: '$userId', startDate: '$startDate', endDate: '$endDate' })
    wiredAssignments(result) {
        this.wiredAssignmentsResult = result;
        if (result.data) {
            this.assignments = result.data;
            this.error = undefined
        } else if (result.error) {
            this.error = result.error;
            this.assignments = undefined;
        }
    }

    handleSubmitAllTimecards() {
        submitAllTimecards({ userId: this.userId, startDate: this.startDate })
        .then((result) => {
            this.disableTimecards = result;
            if (result === true) {
                refreshApex(this.wiredAssignmentsResult);
                //do other stuff

            } else if (result === false) {
                //do something
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**parent.html**

```
<template>
    <template lwc:if={timecards}>
        <template for:each={timecards} for:item="timecard">
                <c-timecard-user-story key={timecard.Id} timecard={timecard}></c-timecard-user-story>
        </template>
    </template>     
</template>
```

**parent.js**

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire } from 'lwc';
import { refreshApex } from '@salesforce/apex';
import getTimecardsByProjectId from '@salesforce/apex/TimecardHelper.getTimecardsByProjectId';

export default class TimecardProjectCard extends LightningElement {
    @api assignment;
    @api userId;
    @api startDate;
    @api disableTimecards;
    timecards;
    wiredTimecardsResult = false;
    error;

    connectedCallback() {
        //do stuff
    }

    @wire(getTimecardsByProjectId, { userId: '$userId', startDate: '$startDate', projectId: '$assignment.Project__c' })
    wiredTimecards(result) {
        this.wiredTimecardsResult = result;
        if (result.data) {
            this.timecards = result.data;
            this.error = undefined;
        } else if (result.error) {
            this.error = result.error;
            this.timecards = undefined;
        }
    }
}
```

**child.html**

```
<template>
    <p>{timecard.Status__c}</p>
</template>
```

**child.js**

```
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';

export default class TimecardUserStory extends LightningElement {
    @api timecard;
}
```

**GetAssignments.cls**

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<Assignment__c> getAssignments(Id userId, String startDate, String endDate) {
        date parsedStartDate = date.parse(startDate);
        date parsedEndDate = date.parse(endDate);

        List<Assignment__c> assignmentList = [SELECT Id, etc FROM Assignment__c WHERE Resource__r.User__r.Id = :userId AND Start_Date__c >= :parsedStartDate AND End_Date__c <= :parsedEndDate WITH USER_MODE];
        return assignmentList;
    }
```

**GetTimecardsByProjectId.cls**

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<Timecard__c> getTimecardsByProjectId(Id userId, String startDate, Id projectId) {
        date parsedStartDate = date.parse(startDate);

        List<Timecard__c> timecardList = [SELECT Id, etc FROM Timecard__c WHERE Resource1__r.User__r.Id = :userId AND Start_Date__c =: parsedStartDate AND Project__c =: projectId WITH USER_MODE ORDER BY CreatedDate ASC];
        return timecardList;
    }
```

**SubmitAllTimecards.cls**

```
@AuraEnabled
    public static Boolean submitAllTimecards(Id userId, String startDate) {
        date parsedStartDate = date.parse(startDate);

        List<Timecard__c> timecardList = [SELECT Id, Status__c FROM Timecard__c WHERE Resource1__r.User__r.Id = :userId AND Start_Date__c =: parsedStartDate WITH USER_MODE ORDER BY CreatedDate ASC];

        List<Timecard__c> timecardsToUpdate = new List<Timecard__c>();
        for (Timecard__c tc : timecardList) {
            if (tc.Status__c != 'Submitted') {
                tc.Status__c = 'Submitted';
                timecardsToUpdate.add(tc);
            }
        }
        try {
            update timecardsToUpdate;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell, in order to refresh the display of the `child` component, the cache of the `parent` (and not necessarily the one of the `grandparent`) needs to be refreshed.

You seem to have guessed so, because the `parent` has an unused

```javascript
import { refreshApex } from '@salesforce/apex';
```

and a variable `wiredTimecardsResult` ready for use.

Just get the two combined, and it should work. Maybe add this to parent and call from grandparent:

```javascript
@api
callRefreshApex() {
    refreshApex(this.wiredTimecardsResult);
}
```

By the way, `grandparent`'s Javascript has api decorators for variables that are written by component code. This appears unnecessary and can even get dangerous, when the variables are not plainly reassigned, but its properties change. (The objects as such are read-only.)

Comment: thanks for the reply. Unfortunately I couldn't get anything working using `refreshApex`. I decided to emit a refresh event from the grandparent using `RefreshView API`. Also thank you for pointing out the unused `@api` variables!

Comment: Not sure why `refreshApex` didn't work. One could of course also [call Apex imperatively](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/apex-call-imperative.html) (e.g. by calling it from the suggested `callRefreshApex()` method and calling this method from the grandparent), which is most of the time the easier approch anyway.

Comment: honestly I could have made a mistake but I have used `refreshApex` plenty and never had issues before. Regardless, it works for me now using `RefreshView API` so I'm happy with that. Thanks for your input though, really appreciate it!